# What's browser support like for bare SWF files?

Tags: actionscript, browser, flash

Does anybody use bare .SWF files as webpages?
I know it's possible; it seems to work fine for me.

Why would I embed a SWF inside an HTML page if it's just going to be full screen *(I mean the size of the browser's normal viewable page area, not COMPLETELY fullscreen)*?

Is there a lack of browser support?
Or is this functionality determined by the browser's Flash plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you embed it in html page and the client doesn't have the flash plugin, most browsers show a missing plugin message. If u directly host the swf, a plugin-less browser might consider it as a download link and try to download the swf into the client machine instead of showing the missing plugin message.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that if the browser has the Flash plugin it will render it, and it's up to you to implement how the swf behaves when you scale/resize the browser window/etc.

You can embed a swf in an HTML page and have it full browser screen offcourse, and you could interact with the browser a bit better ( some nice javascript/flash action going on ), not mention it would be more SEO/standards friendly.

I would recommend using [SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/). Have a look at the [fullpage demo](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/fullpage.html).